# Photo album - jquery ajax json + php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a Photo album using ajax.

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#next').click(function(){

    var next = $('#id').text();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'URL', //This I changed for this post
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "id" : next},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.error);
            if(data.error == true)
            {
                alert(data.msg);
            }
            else
            {
            $('#pics').attr({
                src : data.src,
                witdth : data.width,
                height : data.height});
            $('#id').text(data.id);
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus +' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

php file code:

```
if(is_integer($_GET['id']))
{
$error = false;
$next = $_GET['id'] + 1;

switch($_GET['id'])
{
    case 1: $jsondata = '{"src" : "picture 01 valid path", ';
            $jsondata .= '"width" : xxx, ';
            $jsondata .= '"height" : xxx, ';
            $jsondata .= ' "id" : '.$next;
        break;
    case 2: $jsondata = '{"src" : "picture 02 valid path", ';
            $jsondata .= '"width" : xxx, ';
            $jsondata .= '"height" : xxx, ';
            $jsondata .= ' "id" : '.$next;
        break;
    ...+cases...
    default: $jsondata = '{"msg" : "An error occured. Please close the tab and enter again. Thanks."';
            $error = true;
}

$jsondata .= ', "error" : '.$error.'}';

echo json_encode($jsondata, true);
}
```

html code:
    ‹img src="valid path" width="xxx" height="xxx" /›

With chrome javascript console the error is that 'error' is null. I've being trying a lot of combinations and posibilities around the web without any success! Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.:I'm still not sure if this solution will navigate through the photo album :S That's other question after answering this..

Comment: Check the response using Chrome's inspector or Firebug. Make sure a valid object is coming back and that `data` exists. And replace `alert(data.error);` by `console.log(data);` to see if it's a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a json string in your php code so you dont have to encode it.

Remove this line `echo json_encode($jsondata, true);` from your php code and just `echo $jsondata` and try.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do json_encode, so echo $jsondata should be enough